# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax,

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

I have this **table movies** with **movie_id** and **table actors** with **actor_id** both are connected to **table movie_actor** which contains **actor_id** PK FK and **movie_id** PK FK

I get this eror in Visual Studio Code when I try to run: **php artisan migrate:fresh**

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL: create table `movie_actor` () default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateActorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('actors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('actor_id');
            $table->string('first_name',100);
            $table->string('last_name',100);
        });
        Schema::create('movie_actor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('actor_id')->references('actor_id')->on('actors');
            $table->foreign('movie_id')->references('movie_id')->on('movies');
            $table->primary(['actor_id','movie_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('actors');
        Schema::dropIfExists('movie_actor');
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create the columns before you can create the foreign keys on them. Just adding a foreign key isn't enough to create the column on the table.

Comment: Unless I am missing some Laravel magic, you have to create columns to hold the data before informing MySQL that the column contains a foreign or primary key

Answer (score 1):

`movie_actor` doesn't have any columns defined in it.

Use `foreignId` instead of `foreign` if you want to both create a column and then set as a foreign key but check [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) for the correct syntax because it's not exactly the same. In your case:

```
     Schema::create('movie_actor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('actor_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('movie_id')->constrained();
            $table->primary(['actor_id','movie_id']);
        });
```

This should automatically determine the correct table and id names assuming you are following the conventions.

Note: You can use `constrained('table_name', 'primary_key_name')` to specify exactly what the table and primary key name should be.

Comment: The question shows they aren't following naming conventions; `movies` table has `movie_id` column as PK.